# NHibernate 3.0 Linq query against <map> element instead of using HQL

Tags: linq, nhibernate, dictionary

I have a mapping that looks like this:

```
  <class name="Record">
    <map name="Values">
      <key column="RecordFK"/>
      <index column="FieldFK"/>
      <element column="Value"/>
    </map>
  </class>
```

Translating this to English: a Record maps Fields to Values. In HQL, I can query this map, as follows:

```
from Record rec where rec.Values[:fieldFK] = :value
```

Is it possible to recreate this query using the new Linq provider in NHibernate 3.0 instead of HQL? I tried the following code without success:

```
   var records = session.Query<Record>()
                    .Where(rec => rec.Values[field.Key] == "foo");
```

This produced an error when NHibernate tried to interpret the dictionary accessor:

> System.NotSupportedException:
>   System.String get_Item(System.Int32)

Is there some way to "teach" NHibernate how to turn this C# expression into SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate 3 does have a way to extend the provider to allow more expressions, check http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html

However, this looks like something that should be supported. My suggestion is that you create a ticket at http://jira.nhforge.org with a failing test case.

If you're feeling like doing a little bit more, you can dive into https://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Linq and create a patch. That will make things faster.

**Update** (2010-12-04): My patch has been merged into the trunk. This scenario is now supported (you can compile from source, or wait a few days for the final release)

Comment: I will create a ticket as you suggest. I looked at the info about extending the Linq provider, and I have no idea how to implement the BuildHql override to make this case work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have a proof of concept working; I'll try to upload a patch sometime this week.

Comment: Great, thank you. By the way, the HQL version of this query suffers from a serious bug (http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH-2415). Will the Linq version will have the same problem?

Comment: It's possible. I hope it gets some attention.

Comment: I've uploaded the patch for NH-2416 yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate makes queries pretty simple with CreateCriteria as well.  Heres an example:

```
var records = session.CreateCriteria<Record>()
                     .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Key", "foo)
                     .List<Record>();
```

But NHibernate does have a Linq provider that works as well.  I'm not sure what `Values[field.Key]` but thats probably whats throwing the error. Ideally you should be selecting a "Column" to compare against "foo".

Comment: I don't think the Criteria API supports the <map> element. That's why I'm currently using HQL. A Linq solution would be much better, though.

Comment: As I said NHibernate's Linq works perfectly fine albeit not perfectly optimized.  What is `Values[field.Key]`? I cant help but think theres a better where to compare that in your `.Where` method.